# Vaadin LDAP Login, no ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class to import

Tags: java, maven, ldap, vaadin

I'm trying to create an app in Vaadin with LDAP authentication. I found a code somewhere but I can't import the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class.
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

`http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LdapTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>LdapTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.0.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Here is SecurityConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/#!").permitAll() 
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/VAADIN/**");
    }
}
```

And there is SecurityConfigActiveDirectory class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfigActiveDirectory
{
    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${ldap.domain}")
    String ldapDomain;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()
    {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain, ldapUrl);
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        adProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(getAuthorityMapper());
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(adProvider));
    }

    private static SimpleAuthorityMapper getAuthorityMapper()
    {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        mapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the

> ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider cannot be resolved to a type

And it's impossible to import it. What can I do in that case?

 Greetings, Rafał

Maybe there is a working example of LDAP login in Vaadin 8?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the dependency for `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` in your pom.xml

Comment: @AndréSchild possibly `spring-ldap-core`, `spring-security-ldap` and `unboundid-ldapsdk` as per the [getting started with ldap spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)